# Cross compiling newlib for ARM target in mingw-w64 environment

Tags: arm, mingw-w64, newlib

I'm trying to cross compile the newlib for ARM under the mingw-w64 environment.
Toolchain was downloaded from here: [GNU Arm Embedded Toochain](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads)
Newlib cloned from its [GIT repository](https://sourceware.org/git/newlib-cygwin.git)
I'm running my configuration script from mingw64 shell:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    export PATH=$PATH:/d/Toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.10/bin
    
    ../newlib-cygwin/configure CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi- ARCH=arm CFLAGS="-specs=nosys.specs" \
        --target=arm-none-eabi \
        --prefix="/d/work/newlib-install/" \
        --disable-newlib-supplied-syscalls    \
        --enable-newlib-reent-check-verify    \
        --enable-newlib-reent-small           \
        --enable-newlib-retargetable-locking  \
        --disable-newlib-fvwrite-in-streamio  \
        --disable-newlib-fseek-optimization   \
        --disable-newlib-wide-orient          \
        --enable-newlib-nano-malloc           \
        --disable-newlib-unbuf-stream-opt     \
        --enable-lite-exit                    \
        --enable-newlib-global-atexit         \
        --enable-newlib-nano-formatted-io     \
        --disable-nls
```

And i get an error during configure:

configure: error: in `/d/work/newlib-build' 
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

See `config.log' for more details.

And in config log:

```
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32  
Thread model: posix  
gcc version 9.2.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project)   
configure:4393: $? = 0  
configure:4382: gcc -V >&5  
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'  
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files  
compilation terminated.  
configure:4393: $? = 1  
configure:4382: gcc -qversion >&5  
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?  
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files  
compilation terminated. 
configure:4393: $? = 1  
configure:4413: checking for C compiler default output file name  
configure:4435: gcc -specs=nosys.specs   conftest.c  >&5  
gcc.exe: fatal error: cannot read spec file 'nosys.specs': No such file or directory  
compilation terminated.
```

It means that configure chooses my mingw64 gcc as target compiler instead of arm-none-eabi-gcc.
Is it possible to compile that in mingw64?

Comment: Since newlib is a library, and not a compiler, don't you need `--host=arm-none-eabi` instead of `--target`?

Comment: Thank you for idea. Now configure successfuly finished. But when i'm trying to make, it performs configure in etc folder and after that says:  make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'. So it doesn't show any error but at same time doesn't build.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, do you want to build all of newlib-cygwin, or only newlib? Because since newlib doesn't have a `etc` directory, it looks like you want to build all of newlib-cygwin, but from the description I thought you only want newlib.

Comment: @ssbssa thank you for being confused because your message about that helped me a lot. Initially i supposed that i need to run the _configure_ script in the folder newlib-cygwin which i got after checkout from their GIT repo. But after your last message i realized that i need to run _configure_ from the **newlib** subfolder. And that worked as needed and i was able to successfully compile the library.